# Why is my web site working in VS 2013 but not in IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, vs-web-site-project

I have a web *site* project, that when I debug under the 'default web server' inside VS, it seems to work fine. When I try and debug under IIS or run the site straight from IIS, I get served up a blank page. No error message or log, whether I make `Login.apsx` or 'Default.aspx' my site's default document.

The site is build against .NET 4, and is configured in a .NET 4 Integrated Pipeline app pool. I tried Classic as well with no difference.

Comment: Add a .txt file to your site. Does IIS serve it?

Comment: Are you testing on your localhost(IIS)?

Comment: There isn't a single piece of data on the page?

Comment: What is the status code of the HTTP response ?

Comment: Anything of interest in the eventvwr application log?

Answer (score 2):

Which is first page of your web application ? have you put it as default document ?
Try with following web address and check it browse

```
"http://ipaddressofserver/websitename/page.aspx"
```

Comment: The first page is Default.aspx, and as I said in my question, I have tried making that my default document. I have also tried accessing it directly, by URL, with the same, blank page, result.

Comment: If you run same default.aspx from your localhost, does it shows some text ? have you add some code on page_load ?

Comment: Yes, of course, and I get that content when I run the site in VS, but not IIS, as I said.

Comment: I suggest you to check following link, and see if it helps http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps:

1) Be sure you have enabled the asp.net in IIS from windows feature.

2) Make sure IIS works by opening address `http://localhost:80`

3) Share your website folder with everyone with read access.

4) Add your website in IIS with port number other than 80.

5) Keep the application pool in version 4.0 Integrated.

6) now browse the website.

Comment: +1 these steps are exactly what you should do first of all. Also try to access .txt file as Michael Liu suggested